# Average the value of all the variables groups except one

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
 id    value

  a       2
  b       3
  c       4
  a       6
```

I wish to have average of all the data that **exclude a group**. In other words, I'd like to set  the current id apart and take the average of all the others and repeat it for each id. for instance the first one put  all  `a` apart and take average of `b` and `c` which is 3.5 ( average of 3 and 4) so, I wish to have the following output:

```
 id    value

  a       3.5
  b       4
  c       3.66
```

My data

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c" , "a"), value = c(2,3,4,6) )
```

Note that this question is different from averaging each group

Comment: @MFR Please use the @ so that I will be notified about your comments.  I reopened it.

Comment: Thanks so much  @akrun

Comment: The 3.5 value looks correct, but what about the others? i.e. `mean(c(2,4,6))
#[1] 4`

Comment: The average of 2, 4, 6 is 4

Comment: oops so sorry, It was embarrassing. You're correct.

Comment: In that case, `sapply(as.character(unique(df$id)), function(x) mean(subset(df, !id %in% x)$value))`

Comment: Correct @akrun. Thank you. Please consider posting your answer below, then I can accept it

Comment: If you want the previous output i.e. 6, 5.5, then `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, (sum(df$value) - sum(value))/2 , id]`

Comment: No the first solution  works perfectly, the first output was a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  .(value = (sum(df$value) - sum(value))/(nrow(df)-.N)) , by =  id]
#   id    value
#1:  a 3.500000
#2:  b 4.000000
#3:  c 3.666667
```

If we need the 6 and 5.5 for 'ids' 'b' and 'c'

```
 setDT(df)[, .(value = (sum(df$value) - sum(value))/(uniqueN(df$id)-1)) , by = id]
 #   id value
 #1:  a   3.5
 #2:  b   6.0
 #3:  c   5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plyr::ddply(df,'id',function(x){ c(value = mean(df[with(df,id != x$id[1]),]$value)) })
```